# How Can I Get An Unmodified Copy To Diff In Git

Tags: git

My build is modifying a large file (~256MB) and I want to diff it to the pristine copy. Using a diff tool takes too long and listing the contents is enough for me.

I can do this to list the current contents

```
 unzip -l build.war > current.txt
```

How can I get the unmodified copy from git (so that I can do the same thing then diff the text files)?
Ideally I don't want to reset the current copy (i.e. I want to leave it in its current modified state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the unmodified version with

```
git show HEAD:build.war
```

So to diff the contents of both archives, run:

```
git show HEAD:build.war > build.tmp
unzip -l build.tmp > unmodified.txt
unzip -l build.war > current.txt
diff unmodified.txt current.txt
```

Comment: git show seems to be the answer. However, you can't pipe to unzip like that.

Comment: Wow, thanks. That didn't even occur to me. I modified my answer to reflect that, but it's much less nice now.